# SwiftUI: Absolute positioning of text on screen

Tags: text, swiftui, shapes, frame, cgrect

Am updating a compass view from UIKit to SwiftUI. The original looks like this:

[image]

But haven't worked out how to display the text, currently nothing:

[image]

This is the code that I am using:

```
struct DisplayDirections: Shape {

    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {

        var path = Path()

        let outerRadius = 134.0

        var farX = 0.0

        var farY = 0.0

        let offset = 16.0

        var degree = 0.0

        var radians = 0.0

        for result in ["S", "SW", "W", "NW", "N", "NE", "E", "SE"] {

            radians = (CGFloat(degree) * .pi / 180.0)

            farX = outerRadius + cos(radians) * CGFloat(outerRadius) + offset

            farY = outerRadius + sin(radians) * CGFloat(outerRadius) + offset

            Text(result)

                .font(.title)

                .foregroundColor(.black)

                .background(.red)

                .position(x: farX, y: farY)

                .rotationEffect(.degrees(degree))

                .fixedSize()

            degree = degree + 45.0

            print(result) // Just to get some output so I know the loop is working

        }

        return path

    }

}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to put the writing in a `ZStack` with the `Shape`  I don't think a `Taxt` would work in a `Path` especially with a `for result in ...`, that isn't a `ViewBuilder`

Comment: DisplayDirections() is called from a stack: VStack {
            ZStack {
                Group {
                   …
                    
                   DisplayDirections().  In a similar way that all the other components previously generated line the circle and degree markers are all generated. Text, clearly, works differently.

Comment: I understand but `for result in ...` is not `ViewBuilder` that is what `ForEach` is used for but I don't think it will work in a `func` that returns a `Path` anyway. Everything else you mention is a `Path` of sorts, `Text` are not.

Comment: I've done clocks before so I started playing around to make a compass , I think `Layout` offers the setup that you are looking for.

Comment: I'll look into that - many thanks. Changing the "for" to "ForEach" gave the compiler time out error.

Answer (score 1):

Working, all thanks to Lorem Ipsum's hints. This code has to live in the main Stack and can't be called from Structs like the rest of the lines and circles that make up the clock face. The NSEW literals are put on with a similar construct to the degrees part which are listed below.

[image: Swift UI Version]

```
// Draw Degrees

ForEach(Array(stride(from: 0, to: 360, by: 10)), id: \.self) { index in
    let degree: Double = Double.pi * 2 / Double(360)
    let itemDegree = degree * Double(index)
    VStack {
        Text(String(index))
        .font(.system(size: 8))
        .foregroundColor(.black)
        Spacer()
    }
    .rotationEffect(.radians(itemDegree))
}
.frame(width: 288, height: 288)
```

Comment: Looks good, I ended up going down a rabbit hole and created a Layout similar to the leaderboard form apple's [sample](https://developer.apple.com/wwdc22/10056) it takes the subviews.count to do all the math and placements.